# Python- dataframe loop function decrypt

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe composed of 2 columns 
Let's say the 2 columns are  idencrypted and num.
I use a function decrypt that decrypt column idencrypted and takes 2 other arguments (2 keys of encryption).
I would like to replace the current df or make a new dataframe composed of the id decrypted and the num.
My decrypt function take only string as an entry , that is why I am using a loop like this, and return a string :
Decrypt ('idencrypted', key1, iv)

So I would like a df with id and num column, do you know how can I do? 
Thanks !

Here is my example:
Here is the function decrypt i am using and that is working:

```
for text in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']:  
    print "original:", text  
    dec = decrypt(text,key,iv)  
    print "decrypted:", dec
```

Output:

```
original: 'AAA'  
decrypted: user-111  
original: 'BBB'  
decrypted: user-222
```

But now i have a dataframe as an entry and i would like to put the result in a dataframe.
Example of my dataframe in entry:

```
df=getDataFromDB(engine)
```

The df is composed of 2 columns : idencrypted (like 'AAA','BBB') and  num_col_completed (like '1','2','3')

What i would like as an output is a dataframe with:
iddecrypted splited from 'user-' : ('111','222')
and the num_col_completed : '1','2','3'
so that i can do joins with this dataframe and others after.

I know that i can do the split with : `.split("-")[1]` 
But i do not succeed decrypt all the dataframe ids to an other dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide a [mcve]? If you need help with this, you can find more details at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: i added an example